# how to pass JSON data to restful web services through ajax and also how to get JSON data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, rest

Hi, I am new to JSON .My question is how to pass JSON data to restful web services through ajax?

Please Help me.

I tried by following code but I am not sure about it

**MY INDEX PAGE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){  

     var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value();
     var password = document.getElementById("pwd").value();


     $('#ok').click(function(){  
         $.ajax({  
             url:'http://localhost:8090/LoginAuthRWS/rest/orders',  
             type:'post',  
             dataType: 'Jsondemo',


             success: function(data) {  
                 $('#name').val(data.name);  
                 $('#email').val(data.email);  

                 var JSONObject= {
                         "uname":uname,
                         "password":password
                         };
             }  
         });  
     });  
}); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var JSONObject= {"uname":uname, "password":password };
var jsonData = JSON.parse( JSONObject );    

var request = $.ajax({
  url: "rest/orders",
  type: "POST",
  data: jsonData,
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: using JSON.stringify returning a json string representing the javascript object. JSON.parse converts a string to an javascript object

Comment: you missed contentType: 'application/json'

Comment: In addition, JSON.parse in unnecessary as your jsonObject is currently an object not a string (JSON.parse accepts json style strings and return json style objects).

Answer (score 4):

Problems with your code:

- `.value` is a property not an function
- You want to pass json use `data` of `$.ajax`
- There no data type as `Jsondemo` you have to use `JSON`
- if response `data` is not JSON you can use `$.parseJSON` to convertit to JSON

Complete Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#ok').click(function(){  
        var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
        var JSONObject= {
             "uname":uname,
             "password":password
             };

        $.ajax({  
            url:'http://localhost:8090/LoginAuthRWS/rest/orders',  
            type:'post',
            data :  JSONObject,      
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) { 
                     var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data); //if data is not json
                     $('#name').val(jsonData.name);  
                     $('#email').val(jsonData.email);  
                }  
        });  
    });  
});
```

Comment: you missed contentType: 'application/json'

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery `dataType` Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#dataType).

Possible `dataType` values : `xml`, `json`, `script`, or `html`

**Try this:**

```
var dataToServer = { 
  uname : document.getElementById("uname").value,
  document.getElementById("pwd").value
};

$.ajax({  
  url:'http://localhost:8090/LoginAuthRWS/rest/orders',  
  type:'post',  // or put
  contentType: 'application/json', // type of data
  data: JSON.stringify(dataToServer) // make JSON string
  dataType: 'json', // type of return result
  success: function(data) {  
    $('#name').val(data.name);  
    $('#email').val(data.email);  
  }  
});
```

Comment: You are sending a json style string to the server.  However, you should send the json style object to the server (data: dataToServer).

Answer (score 1):

You want to do something like this:

```
$('#ok').click(function(){  
         $.ajax({  
             url:'http://localhost:8090/LoginAuthRWS/rest/orders',  
             type:'post',  
             dataType: 'json',
             data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }

             success: function(data) {  
                 response = $.parseJSON(data);
                 $('#name').val(response.name);  
                 $('#email').val(response.email);      
             }  
         });  
});
```

A few things to note:

- `dataType` should be almost always `xml` or `json`. Sometimes JQuery can guess correctly if you don't provide anything. But it needs to be a real thing.
- Since you are doing a post, you need to send data to the REST endpoint. That's what I have in `data`. Note that the kind of data matches the value in `dataType`. Also note you can use the `$.post` method to do a much simpler post with JQuery.
- The `data` parameter to the success callback needs to be parsed as JSON first (assuming that's what's coming back) since it is of type `PlainObject` as described [here](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject). That's what `$.parseJSON` does. Once you do that, you can navigate the JSON tree as necessary to do what you need to do. You may be able to get away without doing that though.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

To pass the values to web services Ajax have **data** attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){  

 var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
 var password = document.getElementById("pwd").value;


 $('#ok').click(function(){  
     $.ajax({  
         url:'http://localhost:8090/LoginAuthRWS/rest/orders',  
         type:'post',  
         dataType: 'Json',

         data:{
           uname:uname,
           password:password
         },

         success: function(data) {  
             $('#name').val(data.name);  
             $('#email').val(data.email);
         }  
     });  
  });  
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: @JagathesewarenKuppuraj, `.value` is a property not an function

Answer (score 0):

You can pass json data as request body like this:

```
    var JSONObject= {"uname":uname, "password":password };
    $.ajax({
        url : env + 'rest/orders',
        type : 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        data : JSON.stringify(JSONObject),
        dataType   : "json",
    });
```